# magento sql query update category from inactive to is active

Tags: magento

I currently have an magento site with a couple of hundred categories, the problem I have is the person who added them set is active to NO.  I would like to update all the main and sub categories to is_active to be YES (TRUE).

I have tried the following update Query which updated the is_active to 1 but does not update in Magento even after I re indexed all in Index Management.

```
UPDATE catalog_category_flat_store_1 SET is_active = 1 WHERE is_active = 0
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The `catalog_category_flat_store_1` table is a generated table from the EAV tables done for performance reasons. It's not the true source of the category config data.

You'll need to update the data in the EAV. Run this query to find where `is_active` is stored:

```
SELECT t1.attribute_id, t1.attribute_code, t1.backend_type
FROM eav_entity_type AS t0
INNER JOIN eav_attribute AS t1 ON (t0.entity_type_id = t1.entity_type_id)
WHERE (t0.entity_model = 'catalog/category')
```

On my server it has an `attribute_id` of `42`.

You'll then need to query `catalog_category_entity` and join on `catalog_category_entity_int` to get the rows to update.